# Create namespace in dom element issue

Tags: java, dom, element

Im trying to create XML document with DOM APi's and when i use the following code I got the
expect result

```
Element rootTreeNode = document.createElementNS("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007","ex" + ":Ex")
```

this is the output with tags in output console

```
 ex:Ex Version="1.0" xmlns:ex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007"/
```

Now I want to add to this element the following

```
**xmlns:gp**="http://www.pst.com/Protocols/Data/Generic"
```

and I dont succeed with the **xmlns:gp**  i have tried to use
the like the following

```
rootTreeNode.setAttributeNS("xmlns" ,"gp","http://www.pst.com/Protocols/Data/Generic")
```

and i have got it like the folloing

```
**xmlns:ns0="xmlns"** **ns0:gp**="http://www.pst.com/Protocols/Data/Generic"
```

and if put null in the first  parameter

```
rootTreeNode.setAttributeNS(null ,"gp","http://www.pst.com/Protocols/Data/Generic")
```

I get just **gp** with the **URL** without the xmlns .

what am i doing wrong here ?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Complete test:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

Element root = doc.createElementNS("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007","ex" + ":Ex");
root.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" ,"xmlns:gp","http://www.pst.com/Protocols/Data/Generic");

doc.appendChild(root);

TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
trans.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = sw.toString();

System.out.println("Xml:\n\n" + xmlString);
```

Comment: can you post your complete code? It works for me, output: <ex:Ex xmlns:ex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007" xmlns:gp="http://www.pst.com/Protocols/Data/Generic"/>

Comment: Hello Udo, I use your code and it seems that its working, my question is this is the only way that I can do that ?if for example I need to create instead atc:creatable="false"  what should I put in the method root.setAttributeNS ? Thanks again for your replays!!!

Comment: From mobile, so only short answer, it is the same: root.setAttributeNS("uri.to.atc.schema" ,"atc:creatable","false");

Comment: Hello Udo, Just to verify I need to provide all the namespace in the root in order to use it latter on in the doucment or for every child I need to create namespace if I need to use it later on...     thank you!!!

Comment: In the root is enough, you can also set it e.g. through: root.setAttribute("xmlns:gp","http://www.pst.com/Protocols/Data/Generic"); then reference it later e.g. by simply using: doc.createElement("gp:ElementName");